# Are npm packages equal to node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

What is the difference between `npm packages` vs. `node_modules`?

Or is an `npm package` equal to a `node_module`?

Comment: `node_modules/` is a directory in which NPM packages are stored. There are also Node modules, as distinct from `node_modules/`, which are the modules that ship with Node and are listed in e.g. https://nodejs.org/api/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered by @jonrsharpe:

`node_modules/` is a directory in which NPM packages are stored. There are also Node modules, as distinct from `node_modules/`, which are the modules that ship with Node and are listed in e.g. [nodejs.org/api](https://nodejs.org/api)